# Prince of Darkness goes cryptic

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

No tricks here, just a small cryptic.

> [image]
>
> 1. Reveal dance club around large museum's centre (8)
>   2. The coast is safer not intoxicated (8)
>   3. Party's conclusion to stand by alternative green power (6)
>   4. Patriarch to put me in charge after a second (6)
>   5. A far-right vandal smears shrines (6)
>   6. Purified heart is surrounded by cruel, disfigured Prince of Darkness (7)
>   7. Explorer engaged in oddly angry expression of regret (7)
>   8. Odour is transmitted aurally (5)

Comment: Almost just posted this with the answers still typed in. Note to self: Get your stuff together.

Comment: That would be quite the trick, solving a cryptic that was already solved for us...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Completed Crossword

> [image]

Explanations

1.

> Disclose = Disco around L + mu**se**um

2.

> Seafront = "safer not", anagrammed

3.

> Energy = Green, anagrammed + part**y**.

4.

> Simeon = s + i(me)on, with ion being charge.

5.

> Altars = A + vanda**L** + tars, thanks to Rubio and Hellion for making a better suggestion on this one in the comments.

6.

> Lucifer = Pur**if**ied surrounded by "cruel", anagrammed.

7.

> Apology = Polo within **a**n**g**r**y**

8.

> Scent = sounds like "sent"

Comment: Why is explorer a polo?

Comment: @justhalf Marco Polo - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marco_Polo

Comment: For 5, another possible explanation is that rot13("sne-evtug inaqny" = NY, naq "fzrnef" = "gnef") ?

Comment: @Hellion Probably rot13("**N**" + *sne-evtug* [inaqn] **Y** +  **GNEF** (fzrnef) = **NYGNEF** (*fuevarf*))